# Quadratic Gauss Sums

Tags: gauss-sums

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $\zeta \not = 1$ be a $p^{th}$ root of unity. Let $R$ denote the set of all quadratic residues in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$.
If $\alpha=\sum_{r\in R} \zeta^r$, prove that
$$\alpha (-1-\alpha)=\begin{cases} -\frac{p-1}{4} &,\;\;\mbox{if }\;\; p\equiv 1 \\{}\\\;\;\; \frac{p+1}{4} &,\;\;\mbox{if }\;\; p\equiv 3. \end{cases} \pmod 4$$

I think this is quite famous. Can anyone give me a clue how to go about it?

Comment: $$p=5\;,\;\;\zeta=2\;,\;\;\Bbb F_5^*=\{1,4\}\implies \alpha=2^1+2^4=2+1=3\implies$$

$$\implies\alpha(-1-\alpha)=3(-1-3)=3(-4)=3\cdot 1= 3\neq-\frac{5-1}{4}=-1=4$$

Am I misunderstanding something or there is some mistake/typo in the formulae in the question?

Comment: $\zeta$ is $e^{2\pi i/p}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ denote the quadratic residues(nonzero), and $N$ be the nonresidues.

Consider the sum:
$$
G=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)\zeta^n=\sum_{n\in R} \zeta^n-\sum_{n\in N} \zeta^n=1+2\sum_{n\in R} \zeta^n$$

This can be written as 
$$
G=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{n^2}.$$

For the evaluation of this, see my answer to [A Trigonometric Sum Related to Gauss Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344460/a-trigonometric-sum-related-to-gauss-sums/344485#344485)

$$
G(m)=\sum_{n\textrm{ (mod $m$)}} e\left(\frac{n^2}{m}\right)=\frac{1+i^{-m}}{1+i^{-1}}\sqrt{m}.
$$

This is a special case when $m$ is an odd prime.

Comment: I didn't get how you calculated $G$. It is not there even on the link you gave. Can you explain please?

Comment: On the link, I added a reference. The proof is quite long to be contained here.